# How to Get top 5 Subcategories?

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4

```
<?php $newCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($newSubCategoryId)->limit(5); ?>
```

I'm trying to get top 5 catogeries how can i get?

Comment: top 5 catogeries? sorted by created date or positions or ..?

Answer (score 1):

try below code.

```
<?php $newCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id',array('eq' => $newSubCategoryId))->setPageSize(5); ?>
```

**test code working perfectly**

```
$newSubCategoryId=7;
$newCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id',array('eq' => $newSubCategoryId))->setPageSize(5); 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($newCategory->getData());
```

Comment: it is not working.

Comment: add `->addAttributeToSelect('*')` if you want all attribute @AfzalKhan

Comment: @AfzalKhan tested this code it is working kindly you parent category id

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
$parent_id = 125 ;
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
$children->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $parent_id)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)//get only active categories if you want
        ->setPageSize(5) 
        ->addAttributeToSort('position');//sort by position

foreach ($children as $child){
    //do something with $child
}
```

Comment: why need this if you have already **parent id 5** `$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(5);`?

Comment: @QaisarSatti good catch